# Rearranging Digits of a Number

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many different numbers can be obtained by rearranging the digits of 1,273,421,695?

Would it be C(10,2)*C(10,2)*P(8,6) = 40 million, 824 thousand

Or would it be (10*10*8*8*6*5*4*3*2*1)/(2!*2!) = 1 million 152 thousand

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You must place the two 1s, two 2s and 6 other digits into 10 positions. You can place the 1s in ${10\choose2}$ ways, then the 2s in ${8\choose2}$ ways. The remaining 6 digits must be placed in the remaining 6 positions, so $6!$ ways. Total $907200$. Alternatively, $10!/(2!2!)$: $10!$ is the number of ways of arranging 10 digits, then the two factors of $2!$ remove the duplications from the repeating digits.

Comment: @almagest  You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must place the two $1$s, two $2$s and $6$ other digits into $10$ positions. You can place the $1$s in $10\choose 2$ ways, then the $2$s in $8 \choose 2$ ways. The remaining $6$ digits must be placed in the remaining $6$ positions, so $6!$ ways. Total $907200$. Alternatively, $\frac{10!}{2!2!}.\  10!$ is the number of ways of arranging $10$ digits, then the two factors of $2!$ remove the duplications from the repeating digits.

Posting almagest's comment as an answer so we have a correct one.

Answer (score -1):

Using permutations, I'm pretty sure that it would be 10! which is equal to (10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1).

Hope that helps,
Justin

Comment: No. Because his number has two 1s and two 2s. So you will have duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I know it couldn't just be 10!